# Filter twice in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For `df`

```
    id          Date        ITEM_ID TYPE    GROUP
0   13710750    2019-07-01  SLM607  O       X
1   13710760    2019-07-01  SLM607  O       M
2   13710770    2019-07-03  SLM607  O       I
3   13710780    2019-09-03  SLM607  O       N
4   13667449    2019-08-02  887643  O       I
5   13667450    2019-08-02  792184  O       I
6   13728171    2019-09-17  SLM607  I       I
7   13667452    2019-08-02  794580  O       I
```

reproducible example:

```
data = {'id': [13710750, 13710760, 13710770, 13710780, 13667449, 13667450, 13728171, 13667452],
        'Date': ['2019-07-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-03', '2019-09-03', '2019-08-02', '2019-08-02', '2019-09-17', '2019-08-02'],
        'ITEM_ID': ['SLM607', 'SLM607', 'SLM607', 'SLM607', '887643', '792184', 'SLM607', '794580'],
        'TYPE': ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'I', 'O'],
        'GROUP': ['X', 'M', 'I','N','I','I','I', 'I']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

How can I filter rows where `TYPE==I`, then select: for each row in this filtered dataframe, any rows with the same `ITEM_ID` but `TYPE == O` from all rows in front of it in `df`. Gather these pairs in one dataframe.

I tried selecting the rows where `TYPE==I` using `df[df['TYPE'] == 'I']` and

```
item_list = df[df['TYPE'] == 'I']['ITEM_ID']
df[df.ITEM_ID.isin(item_list )]
```

to filter the rows with the same `ITEM_ID`.

Then, I tried to filter out rows with the same `'GROUP'` using

```
df[df.ITEM_ID.isin(item_list )].apply(lambda x: (x['GROUP'] ==x['GROUP'].shift()))
```

to compare the `GROUP` value, but `shift()` only gets the last one row instead of all previous rows, and it caught error

```
KeyError: 'GROUP'
```

Is there a way to do this?

---

Expected output:
I would like to remove the selected rows

```
    id          Date        ITEM_ID TYPE    GROUP
2   13710770    2019-07-03  SLM607  O       I
6   13728171    2019-09-17  SLM607  I       I
```

and get

```
    id          Date        ITEM_ID TYPE    GROUP
0   13710750    2019-07-01  SLM607  O       X
1   13710760    2019-07-01  SLM607  O       M
3   13710780    2019-09-03  SLM607  O       N
4   13667449    2019-08-02  887643  O       I
5   13667450    2019-08-02  792184  O       I
7   13667452    2019-08-02  794580  O       I
```

---

Update:

Tried:

```
g1 = df.TYPE.eq('I').groupby(df['GROUP'])
g2 = df.TYPE.eq('I').groupby(df['ITEM_ID '])
out = df.loc[g2.transform('any') & g1.transform('any') ]
out.sort_values(by = ['ITEM_ID ', 'Date'])
```

and returned

```
        id          Date        ITEM_ID TYPE    GROUP  
11778   13681604    2019-08-13  101005  O       3.6000   
57196   13737698    2019-09-25  101005  O       0.6000  
95593   13784079    2019-10-29  101005  I       6.1110  
377127  14123909    2020-07-31  101005  O       6.1110  
28298   13702361    2019-08-28  101007  O       1.3260  
33314   13708339    2019-09-02  101007  I       1.3260  
33629   13708722    2019-09-02  101007  O       3.0240  
36599   13712390    2019-09-04  101007  I       3.0240  
123585  13818109    2019-11-21  101007  O       0.5775  
156128  13857644    2019-12-18  101007  O       0.3150  
162086  13864558    2020-01-03  101007  O       0.2500  
162088  13864560    2020-01-03  101007  O       0.2500  
171148  13875226    2020-01-13  101007  I       0.2500  
171149  13875227    2020-01-13  101007  I       0.2500  
171199  13875278    2020-01-13  101007  O       0.5000  
195655  13904483    2020-02-03  101007  O       0.5775  
228820  13944320    2020-03-04  101007  O       0.5250  
233908  13950372    2020-03-09  101007  O       0.5775  
282521  14008271    2020-04-24  101007  O       0.5775  
313485  14046206    2020-05-25  101007  O       0.5775  
319698  14053794    2020-06-01  101007  I       0.5775  
343402  14082826    2020-06-25  101007  O       0.5250  
353516  14095274    2020-07-07  101007  O       0.5250  
377217  14124005    2020-07-31  101007  O       0.5775  
395162  14145686    2020-08-24  101007  O       1.3260
```

was expecting the output to come in pairs, and with `TYPE == O` before `TYPE == I` for each pair, otherwise, ignore it. But it seems there are more `TYPE == O` than `TYPE == I`.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: Hi @BEN_YO please see edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mask and then `ffill()` on `groupby`:

```
s = df.TYPE.eq('I')

mask = s.where(s).groupby(df['GROUP']).ffill()

df[mask.notna()]
```

Output:

```
         id        Date ITEM_ID TYPE GROUP
6  13728171  2019-09-17  SLM607    I     I
7  13667452  2019-08-02  794580    O     I
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Could you please briefly explain line 2 and 3?

Comment: Hi Quang, I think `ITEM_ID` has to be same to qualify as a pair.